# Navigate (switch) between 'Find' and 'code preview' in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Hi I have to make a lot of searches in InteliJ and I want navigate between findings of searched text and code preview of specific file.
I tried to search it on web, and also combination of shortcuts like <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and many more but nothing work.. Do you know how to switch between those two windows?

[image]

right now I have to click it with mouse to focus on one of the windows.

Comment: Similar issue with Find tool window: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181516

Answer (score 1):

The code preview window is intended to be used as exactly that - a preview, not a UI to be used for complex editing operations. If you need to do anything with the search results, use the "Open in Find Window" button to open the toolwindow with the results. After that, you can use for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate between the occurrences, or other keyboard shortcut to switch between the toolwindow and the editor.